# Flutter. ColorFiltered with click through it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using this

```
ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black54, BlendMode.srcOut),
....
```

In order to create an overlay over my entire screen and then I cut out a section of it in order go highlight a widget which is below this overlay. Something similar to this:

[image]

My problem is that the widget behind it, is not clickable. The overlay consumes the click. How can I mark just that particular zone, to be clickable ? Nothing more, nothing less.

**EDIT**

I know I could use `IgnorePointer` but ... if I set it as a parent to `ColorFiltered` it'll just allow all the widget behind the overlay to be clicked. I need it to work ONLY on the highlighted area.

I'm starting to thing I need to rethink the highlighter, in order to achieve this functionality. Am I right ?